# Write dot product of matrices using map in Scheme

Tags: list, dictionary, matrix, scheme

**The main question**: How we should use the map can it handle a list of lists? In other word, supposing we have a list A=(a b c), can map handle the list A just like (map func a b c) ?

---

Here is a detailed description for this question.

Suppose there are 2 matrices:

```
(define v
  (list (list 1 2 3)
        (list 4 5 6)))
(define w
  (list (list 3 2 1)
        (list 6 5 4)))
```

To calculate the dot product of v and w, use map:

```
(define (vector-dot . vectors)
  (map *
       (car vectors)
       (cadr vectors)))
(define (matrix-dot v w)
  (map vector-dot
       v
       w))
```

The code above works well, but if we change the function vector-dot to:

```
(define (vector-dot . vectors)
  (map * vectors))
```

and (matrix-dot v w) will throw an error.

The problem is not why it throws an error, but how we should use the map can it handle a list just like regarding all the elements of this list as arguments?

Comment: Are you familiar with `apply`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `apply`, which compliments rest arguments.

```
(define (vector-dot . vectors)
  (apply map * vectors))

(vector-dot '(1 2 3) '(2 2 2) '(10 11 12))
; ==> (20 44 72)
```

So in this example `vectors` is the list of list like `'((1 2 3) (2 2 2) (10 11 12))` and `(apply map * '((1 2 3) (2 2 2) (10 11 12)))` is the same as `(map * '(1 2 3) '(2 2 2) '(10 11 12))`